# Adobe Analytics visits extracted using R API is smaller than the actual Omniture website

Tags: r, adobe-analytics

I tried to find the solution for this issue (which probably is something simple) but I could not find it. I hope someone could help me.
I just recently started using R to extract data from Omniture Adobe Analytics. 
We currently use Report Builder, but the idea is to start using R.
I'm doing a simple .xlsx data extraction containing data for the different steps of the Sales funnel. Everything worked fine (inclusing ordes, pageviews, etc.), but the visits. I even tried to extract only the visits, but it still brought me the same smaller number.
The number of visits that the R extraction brings is smaller than the actual number obtained at my.omniture.com.
We tried to change the code here and there, but it keeps bringing the same incorrect (smaller) number. 
I need the numbers broken by day.

```
   x = 1
   for (i in reportsuite_id) {
    dataset <-
   QueueDataWarehouse(
  reportsuite.id = reportsuite_id[x],
  date.from = '2017-01-01',
  #date.to = Sys.Date(),
  date.to = '2017-01-02',
  metrics = c('visits'),
  elements = c(),
  date.granularity = 'day',
  enqueueOnly = FALSE
   )
```

I hope someone can help me figure this out.
Thanks!